Como evitar el orWhere si el where se cumple
Tengo los episodios  1 y 2 con traducción en-US y es-MX (por defecto)
Cuando se solicita en en-US y es-MX existe este me trae ambos idiomas como se puede ver en la imagen, como puedo evitar esto?
El ep 6 solo esta en es-MX por eso solo aparece una vez



No sé mucho de SQL, pero en base a esta pregunta, deberías agregar algo como and NOT EXISTS. Sino podrías dejarlo así y filtrar desde el front.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Quizás haciendo dos veces el join con las traducciones, para crear la columna name_$idioma y name_fallback, consigues tener un solo registro por episodio, con una columna para el nombre en el idioma pedido (es) y otro el nombre fallback (en) por si el anterior es nulo.
De esta manera, no repites y el paginador funciona.
